# Does SAP HANA support incremental backup

Tags: hana, database-backups

Does SAP HANA support incremental backup? (backing up the files to which changes are made since the last backup)

If answer is YES, can anyone provide any documentation or example for reference.

Comment: A similar result would be to do regular log backups in between snapshots.  https://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-62435

Answer (score 1):

Yes from sp10 sap hana supports incremental backup.
have you checked the below link ?

http://saphanawiki.com/2015/07/29/incremental-and-differential-backup-in-sap-hana/

Comment: just having a link as answer is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, up to and including SPS 9 incremental backups are not supported.